# Using 500+ Char Strings with Google AppEngine Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to store a Document to the Google AppEngine Datastore. At first I tried using a Text object, but the stored text became truncated by some kind of indexing I was not able to find any information about. I now get the error: `test.at.example.com: com.google.appengine.api.search.Document is not a supported property type.` How can I store a `String` longer than 500 characters?

This is the method to store the String:

```
public String post(String user, String documentText) {
        if (!documents.hasProperty(user)) {
            String indexesstr = (String) documents.getProperty(INDEXLABEL);
            documents.setProperty(INDEXLABEL, indexesstr + "\n" + user);
        }
        documentText = documentText.replace("<", "&lt;");
        documentText = documentText.replace("\n", "<br>");
        documentText = documentText.replace("\r", "<br>");
        Document doc = Document.newBuilder()
                .addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("user").setText(user))
                .addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("content").setText(documentText))
                .build();
        documents.setProperty(convertId(user), doc);

        datastore.put(documents);
        return makeIndex();
}
```

This is my method for retrieving the data:

```
public String getDocument(String contextPath) {
        int offsSlash = contextPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
        String ID = contextPath.substring(offsSlash,
                contextPath.lastIndexOf("."));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(prependHTML);
        Document document = (Document) documents.getProperty(convertId(ID));
        if (document == null)
            sb.append("Document not found.");
        else {
            sb.append(document.getOnlyField("document").getText());
            sb.append("<br><div align=\"right\">");
            sb.append(document.getOnlyField("user").getText());
            sb.append("</div>");
        }
        sb.append(ammendHTML);
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Text value type. It's not truncated. This value type cannot be indexed.

See the list of supported value types for properties here:

[Properties and value types](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types)

If you need to search inside a text string, you need to use the Search API. It has its own methods for inserting and retrieving documents - you cannot store a Document object in a property of a datastore entity.

Comment: Thanks. I just now learned I was using the `Text` object incorrectly. I was calling `toString` instead of `getValue`.